# How can I make the pop up stay and not make it go to another page?

Tags: html, css

I am new to programming and I'm not sure what I'm going to do anymore, I'm at a loss.
The thing is, our teacher wants us to have like a pop up alert message when he presses submit on our sign up webpage that confirms that the sign up was successful. The issue for my webpage is that whenever I click submit, it goes to another page. thank you for your time.

[This is the thing our teacher assigned us for our finals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQSUt.gif)

```css
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #362204;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.imgcontainer {
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}

img.avatar {
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
     display: block;
     float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
     width: 100%;
  }
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  padding-top: 60px;
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button (x) */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}
  
@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {transform: scale(0)} 
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
     display: block;
     float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
     width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register Now!</title>    
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
    form {border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;} 
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<body style="background-color: #FFB6C1">
<h2><center><img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo" width="300"/></center></h2>
<form action="/actionpage.php" onsubmit="yourJsFunction();return false">
  <div class="imgcontainer" style="background-color:#fff">
    <br><center><img src="avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar"
     height="250"/></center>


    <h1><left>&nbsp&nbspCreate a New Account</h1>
    <p>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspPlease fill in this form to become a member, master!</p>
    <hr>

    <label for="email"><b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspEmail</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspPassword</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" id="psw" required>

    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspRetype Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Retype Password" name="psw-repeat" id="psw-repeat" required>
    <hr>
    <p>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspBy creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto return false;">Sign Up</button>

<div id="id01" class="modal">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
  <form class="modal-content" action="/action_page.php">

    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
      <center><img src="check.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar"></center>
    <h1><center>Success!</center></h1>
        <p><center>Thank you for joining! We hope to see you more often, Master Patron!</center></p>
</div>
</div>

    <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>


    <span class="psw"><a href="#">Already a Master Patron?</a></span>

  </div>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just change Sign up button tag to : <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block';" style="width:auto">Sign Up</button>      and from "form" tag remove "action" and "onclick" your work done. but you html has many missing tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get that alert message on clicking of the sign up button, you should remove the get.php from action tag of the html code.
I created a function of Javascript for that alert message of Signup was successful.
I added that function in the form tag of onsubmit attribute as it will call my function when the user press the submit button of the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Register Now!</title>    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
form {border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;} 
</style> 
<style>
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
   width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #362204;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
   border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.imgcontainer {
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}

img.avatar {
   width: 20%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
     display: block;
     float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
     width: 100%;
  }
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
 position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%; /* Full width */
 height: 100%; /* Full height */
 overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
 background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
 padding-top: 60px;
 }

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button (x) */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {transform: scale(0)} 
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
       display: block;
     float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
     width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
    <body>
    <body style="background-color: #FFB6C1">
    <h2><center><img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo" width="300"/></center></h2>
    <form action="" onsubmit="alertMessage();return false"> <!----here I added the function alertMessage() in onsubmit attribute such that whenever a user submit the form, it will call the js function------>
      <div class="imgcontainer" style="background-color:#fff">
        <br><center><img src="avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar"
 height="250"/></center>


    <h1><left>&nbsp&nbspCreate a New Account</h1>

<p>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspPlease fill in this form to become a member, master!</p>
    <hr>

    <label for="email"><b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspEmail</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspPassword</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" id="psw" required>

    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspRetype Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Retype Password" name="psw-repeat" id="psw-repeat" required>
    <hr>
    <p>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspBy creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto return false;">Sign Up</button>


<div id="id01" class="modal">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times; 
</span>
  <form class="modal-content" action="/action_page.php">

    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times; 
   </span>
      <center><img src="check.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar"></center>
            <h1><center>Success!</center></h1>
               <p><center>Thank you for joining! We hope to see you more often, 
   Master Patron!</center></p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>


    <span class="psw"><a href="#">Already a Master Patron?</a></span>

  </div>
    <script>
    // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    alert("signup was successful");
  }
}
// The function needed for an alert message
function alertMessage(){
    alert("Signup was successful!!");
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you click on submit button in a form, the default behavior of form is to redirect to the `action` page, so you may need to use eventlistener for this to work

```
let submitForm = document.getElementById('submit-form');
submitForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    openModal(); 
    //choose whatever function you want to call or 
    //action you want to take when submitting form
});
```

This will not redirect you to another page

**NOTE** : This is not an ideal way for form submission, if you know how to work with **AJAX** you should try that for form submission.